# Google maps... gestureHandling on mobile not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, mobile

Hoping you could help... I'm a little stumped...  Basically, I have a google map, with autocomplete working.  You search an origin and destination and my correct, set filtered results/markers appear on the map.

However, when I view my map on mobile, via chrome/safari, the map does not move and you can not interact with it at all.

I've googled and understand I need gestureHandling: 'cooperative'.  However, as my app is built in anjular JS and my google maps code sits in a directive, I'm not sure where to place this...

Here's a relevant snippet of my directive:

```
googleMap.$inject = [];
function googleMap() {

return {
restrict: 'E',
template: '<div class="google-map"></div>',
replace: true,
scope: {
  center: '=',
  zoom: '=',
  origin: '=',
  destination: '=',
  travelMode: '=',
  foodType: '='
  // gestureHandling: '='
},

link($scope, $element) {
  const map = new google.maps.Map($element[0], {
    zoom: $scope.zoom,
    center: $scope.center,
    // gestureHandling: 'cooperative',

  });

  map.setOptions({gestureHandling: 'cooperative'});
  const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  const directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  const placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  const directionsShow = document.getElementById('bottom-panel');


  const image = {
    url: '/assets/images/marker.gif', // url
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(60, 60), // scaled size
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0) // origin
  };


  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
```

However, when i drop {gestureHandling: 'cooperative'} into "return", my map still isnt working on mobile.

I've even tried dropping in, the below code in my directive.  Doesn't work.
   map.setOptions({gestureHandling: 'cooperative'});

Here's how the google map is looking in my views folder.  I even tried dropping it here...

```
<google-map zoom="14" center="{ lat: 51.513172, lng: -0.111997 }" 
origin="pagesHome.origin" destination="pagesHome.destination" travel- 
mode="pagesHome.travelMode" food-type="pagesHome.foodType">
</google-map>
```

Kinda stumped I can't get this working!

Thanks, 
Reena

Answer (score 1):

thanks for coming back to me.  It turns it the issue was being caused by CSS. There was a zindex set to -1 on the map.  And it basically stopped the map from working...

Thanks for your response though!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
googleMap.$inject = [];
function googleMap() {

return {
restrict: 'E',
template: '<div class="google-map"></div>',
replace: true,
scope: {
  center: '=',
  zoom: '=',
  origin: '=',
  destination: '=',
  travelMode: '=',
  foodType: '=',
  gestureHandling: '='
},

link($scope, $element) {
  const map = new google.maps.Map($element[0], {
    zoom: $scope.zoom,
    center: $scope.center,
    gestureHandling: $scope.gestureHandling

  });

  //map.setOptions({gestureHandling: 'cooperative'});
  const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  const directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  const placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  const directionsShow = document.getElementById('bottom-panel');


  const image = {
    url: '/assets/images/marker.gif', // url
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(60, 60), // scaled size
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0) // origin
  };


  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
```

HTML

```
<google-map zoom="14" center="{ lat: 51.513172, lng: -0.111997 }" 
origin="pagesHome.origin" destination="pagesHome.destination" travel- 
mode="pagesHome.travelMode" food-type="pagesHome.foodType" gesture-handling="cooperative">
</google-map>
```

Comment: Hiya, thanks for coming back to me.  It turns it the issue was being caused by CSS. There was a zindex set to -1 on the map.  And it basically stopped the map from working...

Thanks for your response though!